# Salesforce user interface Clone vs DeepClone in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

We have a standard Clone and a standard DeepClone buttons on Opportunities and we'd like to do something different in the after insert trigger when the user presses the DeepClone button.

I can see that the opportunity was created from a clone in the trigger by using opportunity.isClone() but I can't distinguish between a regular clone or a DeepClone. I also inspected the populated fields map but it seems like both buttons produced the same data. Is there a way to determine which button was pressed in the trigger?

```
trigger OnOpportunity on Opportunity (after insert) {
    for(Opportunity opportunity: trigger.New){

       System.debug('isClone():' + opportunity.isClone());
       System.debug('getCloneSourceId():' + opportunity.getCloneSourceId());
            
       Map<String, Object> fieldsToValue = opportunity.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
     
       for (String fieldName : fieldsToValue.keySet()){
          System.debug('field name is ' + fieldName + ', value is ' + 
                        fieldsToValue.get(fieldName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the trigger's point of view,  they are the same operation.  You would need to have an Apex class set a static variable,  then start the DML operation.  The trigger could then check the variable to see if it's a deep clone or not.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, that's what I was afraid of.